# Simplenews test newsletter send by smtp: how to avoid?

Tags: emails

I'm sending my newsletters by [Drupal Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) + [smtp-module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp).

When sending the mailing the smtp-provider puts it in a queue and that causes a delay from maximum 15 minutes. That's ok.

The problem is that the test newsletter is also send by de smtp-service and arrives with 15' minutes delay. Not very handy when we're preparing a mailing.

Does someone knows a method to avoid that the testmail is send by smtp but by the localhost?